# angularfire routing the pages on two or three clicks of a button

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a controller for signing in firebase

```
        $scope.addUser = function() {

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.Email,$scope.Password).then(function(authData) {
    authenticated = true;
    console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid, authenticated);
    $location.path("/user_manual");

}).catch(function(error) {
    authenticated = false;
    console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    $location.path("/");

});

};
```

And a login.html form

```
  <center><h1>Login</h1></center>

  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="Email"
               ng-model="Email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

      <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password"
               ng-model="Password" placeholder="Password"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a ng-click="addUser()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Login</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

As I click on login button it doesn't load user_manual.html for the first time but clicking it on three times it loads user_manual.

The same is with logout button:

I have logout function :

```
       scope.logout = function(){

       $window.alert("Do you really want to logout?");
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
         $location.path("/");
       }).catch(function(error) {

        });
```

And a logout button as:

```
      <a ng-click="logout()" ng-confirm-click="Do you want to logout" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">logout</a>
```

It also redirects to $location.path("/") on clicking the button twice.

Here is the main controller app.js:

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','firebase','ng-fusioncharts','chart.js','720kb.datepicker']);
            var config = {

               *******************************
              };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            app.config(function($routeProvider){
              $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'UserAdd',
                    templateUrl: 'views/users/user_login.html'
                })
                .when('/user_manual', {
                    controller: 'UserManual',
                    templateUrl: 'views/user_manual/user_manual.html'
                })


             .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
            });
```

Why the buttons not work on a single click action?

Comment: please notice the tagging. You should have tagged "angularJS" since "angular"-tag refers to angular 2 ->

Comment: I edited the tag for you, removed the angular tag and replaced it with angularjs, as you can see I have edited the post ;) But for future reference this could be good to remember.

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks for the good advice